# I am trying to pass a variable that contains a string e.g. "allure.serverity_level.CRITICAL" into the notation @allure.severity()

Tags: python, allure

it doesn't accept it. I tried creating different functions as well but their placement is not above the method i want to use this notation above. Please check the image attached.
Here I tried putting all possible severities in a function but it doesn't work.

I am wondering how type casting will be helpful here but I am not sure how...

```
#creating a function to accept dynamic input for severity.
code: def set_allure_severity():
    TestCase_Severity = get_tc_severity()
    if TestCase_Severity == "BLOCKER":
        @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.BLOCKER)
    elif TestCase_Severity == "CRITICAL":
        @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.CRITICAL)
    elif TestCase_Severity == "NORMAL":
        @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.NORMAL)
    elif TestCase_Severity == "MINOR":
        @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.MINOR)
    elif TestCase_Severity == "TRIVIAL":
        @allure.severity(allure.severity_level.TRIVIAL)

#calling the function:
set_allure_severity()
```

Comment: please edit the post and add the code as text with proper formatting. Do not use images to show your code.

Comment: I am sorry. Should've read the rules!